# Vue Router Replace function still trigger created() lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a view page view with multiple tabs inside. When tab's index change I update.

This is when you click on tab  "Info"
 `this.$router.replace({query: { section: 'Info'} })`

What I wanna see is - *myUrl/10/section=Info*
and when I moved to Detail tab - *myUrl/10/section=Detail*

But it still triggers the **created() function and page  - reload.**
This is my router section for this component

```
            path: ":id/",
            component: AdminOrganizationDetailComponent,
            name: "csm.organizations.detail",
          }
```

:id is a parameter  -  I did not assign anything related with query on here.

Answer (score 0):

your url must look like that `myUrl/10?section=Info` and you can do that by :

```
this.$router.replace('myUrl',{params:{id: 10},query: { section: 'Info'} });
```

but i prefer to use nested routes , you can read about it [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

Comment: This section is under the same component. I am not sure that nested route will help because I won't go to another page. I just want to update URL without refreshing the page